# "Pointer being freed was not allocated" while deleting allocated (?) pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, c++14, clion

The error occurs at the "delete pointer;"

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    int* pointer = &i;
    *pointer = 0;
    std::cout << "Value: " << i << std::endl;
    delete pointer;
    std::cout << "This does not print" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value: 0
untitled1(11320,0x106c20dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffeeeb00948: pointer being freed was not allocated
untitled1(11320,0x106c20dc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Process finished with exit code 6
```

OS: macOS Catalina 10.15.6 (19F101)

C++14

CMake: 3.16.5 (bundled with CLion)

Output from gcc -v:

```
❯ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Please read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) book, then [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), the C++11 standard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't allocated any pointer. You're also confused over terminology. Allocation here is refering to *dynamic* allocation. In dynamic allocation you allocate *memory* and you assign the address of that memory to a pointer. Memory is allocated with `new`

So the correct version of your code is

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int* pointer = new int(5);
    *pointer = 0;
    std::cout << "Value: " << *pointer << std::endl;
    delete pointer;
    std::cout << "This does print" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When you allocate memory with `new` you should free it with `delete`. Otherwise you get what is called a *memory leak*. Unchecked memory leaks would eventually mean your program runs out of memory to allocate.

Comment: The original code works fine (?) on my machine though. Why you're not supposed to use `delete` when making a pointer from an existing variable? (using &). I'm still pretty new to this pointer stuff so I'm just asking out of curiosity. I thought the pointer needs to be removed even if it points to an existing variable?

Comment: `delete` only needs to be used with `new` (and `delete[]` needs to be used with `new[]`). Not sure where you got the idea that all pointers need to be deleted, that's just completely wrong. Remember what's being deleted is the **memory** not the pointer. So if you have two pointers pointing to the same block of dynamically allocated memory, you would only need one delete. Remember memory is deleted not pointers, that's the terminology mistake I mentioned before.

Comment: The reason your code worked on one machine and not on another is because of *undefined behaviour*. Bad C++ programs don't have to crash, or produce error messages, all they have is undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen when you run them, including 'working'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You should only `delete` pointers that have been allocated with `new`. Pointers to other objects will get invalidated (which is sort of like deleted, but not quite) automatically when the object goes out of scope so you don't have to worry about it.